# Error using RealmList with Moshi

Tags: android, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list, moshi

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform java.lang.Class annotated [] requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered

I get the above error when using a RealmList with Moshi.

```
public class MenuModel implements RealmModel
{
    @Json(name = "menugroups")
    private RealmList<MenuGroupModel> menugroups = null;
}
```

I have researched this a bit and found the following:

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2711

The solution there says I need to use a **RealmListAdapter**. I have copied the code to my project. I, however, have no idea how and where to implement this adapter.

How do I use it?

Comment: Register it on your Moshi instance. `Moshi.Builder.add(RealmListAdapter.FACTORY)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go here:
[Regalia Moshi](https://github.com/Commit451/Regalia/tree/master/regalia-moshi)

Copy both **RealmListAdapter** and **RealmListAdapterJsonFactory** to your project (or use the linked project). Add the adapter to your moshi like this:

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder()
.add(new RealmListJsonAdapterFactory())
.build();
```

Further usage, if you're using Retrofit:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API.ENDPOINT)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .build();
```